# Filemaker 13 ODBC Firebird connection possible?

Tags: php, sql, odbc, firebird, filemaker

I want to connect a Filmaker 13 Database with a Firebird Database trough ODBC.

So far I could connect with a another programm to the Firebird DB from another PC (Win 7 on all PCs). I also have another connection from a telefon software. So there is no issue on that side.

When I try to connect to the ODBC DNA Filemaker sayes that this datasource is not supported.

Comment: Is Filemaker 32 bit or 64 bit, make sure the ODBC driver is the same bitness (and if you use ODBC Administrator: use the right ODBC administrator (there are 2: 64 bit: System32\odbcad32.exe, and 32 bit: SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe). BTW: Bitness of the server is irrelevant.

Comment: i can only use the 64 Bit ODBC driver, the other is not giving me a connection (within the ODBC 32 OR ODBC 64 Administrator)

Comment: But the question is: Is it working general? I am now about 1H later i read trough the ODBC driver PDF on the Filmeaker site and it only gives compatinility for MYSQL and MS SQL and Oracel etc.

Comment: Sorry I forgot: I tried both 32 and 64 Firebird ODBC Driver, Filemaker Pro 13 is 32 Bit only. So you mean i should try to use the 32 Bit Version? So far i had no luck using this.

Comment: A 32 bit application cannot use a 64 bit driver, so you need to use the 32 bit ODBC driver.

Comment: I just did a new installtion. On a 64 Bit Win 8.1 I installed 32Bit ODBC Firebird Driver and used the 32 ODBC Admin pannel to connet to a external firewird server wich i was able to connect trough the admin panel. After that i tried to connect from FM Pro 13 and it told me that this DATA source is not supported again.

Comment: According to http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/odbc.html ODBC is supported; chapter 2 of https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/13/en/fm13_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf describes how to configure it. According to the documentation it needs to be a **system dsn**, not a user dsn

Answer (score 0):

To answere my own question:

Its not possible trough ODBC, its simply not supported.